# Why Ajax search returning 0?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a page where I am showing the posts of a custom type in wordpress. Basically, there are checkboxes to search posts based on taxonomy using Ajax. But the result is showing 0 in incognito mode and Firefox. But, in my google chrome, it is working fine. I have used die() and ajax callback is properly defined. Could you please check that where I am missing. I have `ajax.php` file which is included in `functions.php`,

```
<?php 
add_action('wp_head', 'wp_ajax_url');
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'include_ajax_js');

function wp_ajax_url(){
    $script = '<script>';
    $script .= 'var ajax_url = " ' . admin_url('admin-ajax.php') . ' " ; ' ;
    $script .= '</script>'; 
    echo $script;
}

function include_ajax_js() {
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/jquery.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
}

add_action('wp_ajax_search', 'search');
add_action('wp_ajax_no_priv_search', 'search');

function search(){
    $skill = $_POST['skill'];
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $certification = $_POST['certification'];
    //echo $skill, $type, $certification; die();

    if(!empty($skill) && !empty($type) && !empty($certification)){
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'myguncourse',
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'skilllevel',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => array( $skill ),
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'firearmtype',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => array( $type ),
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'certification',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => array( $certification ),
            ),
        ),
    );

} else if ( !empty($skill) && !empty($type )) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'myguncourse',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'skilllevel',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => array( $skill ),
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'firearmtype',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => array( $type ),
            ),
        ),
    );
} else if ( !empty($skill) && !empty($certification)) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'myguncourse',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'skilllevel',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => array( $skill ),
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'certification',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => array( $certification ),
            ),
        ),
    );
} else if ( !empty($type) && !empty($certification)) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'myguncourse',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'firearmtype',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => array( $type ),
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'certification',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => array( $certification ),
            ),
        ),
    );
} else if ( !empty($skill)) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'myguncourse',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'skilllevel',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => array( $skill ),
            ),

        ),
    );
} else if ( !empty($type)) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'myguncourse',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'firearmtype',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => array( $type ),
            ),

        ),
    );
}  else if ( !empty($certification)) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'myguncourse',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'certification',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => array( $certification ),
            ),

        ),
    );
}  else {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'myguncourse',
    );
}

    $query = new WP_Query($args); 

    if( $query->have_posts()) :
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    ?>
   <h4 style="display: inline;"><?php the_title();?></h4>
   <h5 style="display:inline;" class="pull-right"></h5>
   <p><?php the_content();?></p> 
   <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" align="right"><b>VIEW THIS COURSE </b></a><hr>

   <?php
    endwhile; endif;
    //wp_reset_query();
    die();     
}
?>
```

Andmy jquery file is as follows:

```
(function($) {


 $(".chb1").change(function () {
 $(".chb1").not(this).prop('checked', false);
 });

 $(".chb2").change(function () {
 $(".chb2").not(this).prop('checked', false);
 });

 $(".chb3").change(function () {
 $(".chb3").not(this).prop('checked', false);
 });


 $('#myForm input').on('change', function() {
  skill = $('input[name=skill]:checked', '#myForm').val();
  type = $('input[name=type]:checked', '#myForm').val();
  certification = $('input[name=certification]:checked', '#myForm').val(); 
   $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: ajax_url,
      data: { action: 'search', skill : skill, type : type, certification : certification },
      success: function(response){
          $('.article').html(response);
          //console.log(response);
      }
  })
 });

})(jQuery);
```

It is working fine in my browser, but in chrome's incognito mode and other browser like firefox, it's returning 0. It is also returning 0 in my friend's google chrome. Could you please guess the mistake. In my browser, search is working fine.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ajax+returns+0&oq=ajax+returns+0&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1693j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 - any of these relevant?

Comment: No....Intrestingly, In my chrome browser, it is working. But in other browser it is resulting 0. Also, it;s returning 0 in my friend's google chrome browser. But it is working fine in my chrome browser(not in incognito).

Comment: 'wp_ajax_no_priv_search' -> 'wp_ajax_nopriv_search'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! You are doing a mistake here:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_no_priv_search', 'search');
```

So, the users who are not logged in, will not able to see the result. You must correct that to:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_search', 'search');
```

nopriv is used for the users who are not logged in. so you were not able to see the result.